# Joining two table in one condition

Tags: mysql, sql, vb6, firebird

I have two tables, tblstudent and tbltrans, tblstudent contains idstudent and nmstudent, in tbltrans containing idtrans, idstudent, trprice
I want to merge those two tables so that the result becomes nmstudent and trprice but I want the idstudent that does not exist in tbltrans can also be displayed with the contents of "-"
please help
[Joining two table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zEx8.jpg)

Comment: HINT: `SQL Left join`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Firebird? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

combine left join and coalesce:

```
select
    nmstudent,
    coalesce(trprice,'-')
from
    tblstudent
    left join tbltrans on
        tblstudent.idstudent=tblstudent.idstudent
```

Comment: thank you, I have another question but I can only post it once in 90 minute...can you answer it again? its similiar question but adding some value of SUM

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT nmstudent, CASE WHEN tprice IS NULL THEN "-" ELSE tprice END as tprice
FROM tblstudent LEFT JOIN tblstudent
ON tblstudent.idstudent = tbltrans.idstudent
```